# How to delete by bulk URL redirects for a specific content type?

Tags: redirection

For a content node say "foo1" I would like to delete all URL redirects. How to do this?

I tried views but do not get the node type in the relation. I can find several answers which updates url aliases (path auto module) but all these solutions do not delete the url redirects from [redirects](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module.

Any solution is more then welcome. Whatever form is rules, programming...

Comment: Only 244 sites use URL Redirect module, you should've gone with the far more popular [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module instead

Comment: Sorry type, I use the redirect module. I will edit my initial question